# DHTMLX - Bind form and grid doesn't work

Tags: forms, grid, bind, dhtmlx

I try to bind a form with a grid. My grid is on the main  and my form is inside a window popup.

My code for the form :

```
var window_1 = windows.createWindow('window_1', 0, 0, 385, 340);
window_1.setText('Modifier une absence');
window_1.denyMove();
window_1.setModal(1);
window_1.centerOnScreen();
window_1.denyResize();
window_1.denyPark();
window_1.button("minmax").hide();
window_1.button("park").hide();
window_1.button("close").disable();

form_window = window_1.attachForm();
form_window.loadStruct('./data/formAddAbsence.xml');
form_window.bind(grid_3);// to link the form to the grid

form_window.attachEvent("onButtonClick", function(name, command){
    if(name=="buttonEnregistrer"){
        this.send("editEmployee");
        sidebar.cells('sidebar_item_1').setActive(true);
        window_1.close();
    }
    if(name=="buttonAnnuler"){
        sidebar.cells('sidebar_item_1').setActive(true);
        window_1.close();
    }
});
```

grid_3 is defined before with :

```
var grid_3 = sidebar.cells('sidebar_item_1').attachGrid();
grid_3.setIconsPath('./codebase/imgs/');

grid_3.setHeader(["Nom","Prénom","Statut","Équipe","Début","Fin","Motif"]);
grid_3.setColumnIds("nom,prénom,statut,team,startDate,endDate,type");
grid_3.setColTypes("ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro,ro");

grid_3.setColSorting('str,str,str,str,str,str,str');
grid_3.setInitWidths('*,*,*,*,*,*,*');
grid_3.init();
grid_3.sync(absencesDataStore);
```

The ids of the grid and the names of the form are the same. (the code works in other parts of my website but the forms are not in a window popup).

The problem is : The form seems not bound to the grid.

Comment: Additionnal information : the window is created when an event is catched.

Comment: I just changed other part of the code. When I move the form into window, the bind doesn't work.

Comment: the problem is the asynchrone approach :). The form load his structure and directly I try to bind with the grid. Now, I'm using the doOnLoad of the form, and then I bind with the grid. That works !

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the asynchrone approach :). The form load his structure and directly I try to bind with the grid. Now, I'm using the doOnLoad of the form, and then I bind with the grid. That works !